# How do websites like Facebook handle object relationships?

Tags: php, web-applications

I am trying to get into some more advanced web development techniques and have a few projects in mind that require object relationships.  I am developing in PHP and am planning on making the site completely object orientated.

Websites like Facebook have relationships between users, friends, groups, events, likes, posts, comments, ect.  A user can belong to a group or many groups and a group can have many users. This same kind of relationship is true for events, likes, posts, comments, ect. So my question is how are these relationships handled and saved?

Obviously there is a very complex database that holds the actual content but when defining relationships such as "Which user belongs to which groups?", how is this handled? Would all groups have a unique identification such as a hash or id number? And then a user has a "mygroups" array or such that continues to add/delete group ids which render the user a part of a group or not.

I may be way off track but any light shed on my question would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example. Users and Group.

It is  a MANY to MANY relation ship. That means one user can be in 0 ore more group and One group can have one ore more  Users

So There will be 3 Tables

**USER Table**

```
USER_ID (INT) Primary Key
USER_NAME V(VARCHAR)
```

**GROUP Table**

```
GROUP_ID (INT) Primary Key
GROUP_NAME (INT)
```

**USER_GROUP**

```
USER_GROUP_ID (INT) Primary Key
GROUP_ID (INT) Foriegn Key (to GROUP Table, GROUP_ID Column)
USER_ID (INT) Foriegn Key (to USERTable, USER_ID Column)
```

Some sample data will be like

**USER**

```
 USER_ID              USER_NAME
 --------------------------------
 1                    Scott
 2                    Jon
 3                    Mike
```

**GROUP**

```
 GROUP_ID              GROUP_NAME
 --------------------------------
 161                    Bloggers
 162                    Geeks
```

**USER_GROUP**

```
 USER_GROUP_ID   USER_ID              GROUP_ID
 ----------------------------------------------
   1                1                    161
   2                2                    161
   3                2                    162
   4                3                    161
```

This means

1) Scott, Jon & Mike are present in Bloggers group.

2) Scott is present int eh Geeks group.

Comment: So basically all relationships are handled in the database. The data is just parse server-side and displayed via the client using javascript or in Facebook's situation, probably some custom framework

Comment: @MattHintzke: Facebook uses a lot of async calls from client side to load parts of the page(pagelets they call ?), once you get the data from tables, it is up to you to decide how to show it in the UI

Answer (score 1):

Someone more familiar with the subject would likely be able to shed more light on it, but yes, you are correct: Each group, user, etc has a unique ID. Relationships between users and groups ,as well as friend relationships all exist in tables in a relational database.

I'd say that the database is likely not quite as complex as you think. If a user has a userid, then friendships, could be represented in a friendship table, such as:

```
Friendship table
----------------
  UserID | FriendID
  User_A | Friend_1
  User_A | Friend_2
  etc...
```

Group Membership:

```
 Groupmembership table
  GroupID | UserID
   GroupA | User1
   GroupA | User2
   etc...
```

I am not saying that you should do it like this, but this is one possible solution: Using a regular relational database.

For Facebook, the real complexity likely lies in optimizing the performance of their massive databases.

Comment: that makes sense. I  understand how to construct a relational database,  I am just sure on the methodology of actually inserting data into it so that all the relationships hold.